# way to start and stop RabbitMQ mannually

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed RabbitMQ/Celery on Ubuntu for queuing of videos for Video conversion server which will start and shut down based upon the queue of videos i.e

Start - As soon as a video is uploaded for the conversion

Shut - As soon as all videos in queue are completed and done with.

Is there way to achieve this?

Comment: You'd probably create a larger overhead by starting and stopping the queues than by leaving them be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to only stop queues or if you want to stop the rabbitmq server.  For the server, if you can run commands, then you can use `rabbitmqctl`.

**Start:**
rabbitmqctl start_app

**Stop:**
rabbitmqctl stop_app

I'm not sure there is any concept of starting and stopping queues in rabbitmq.